# how do I name objects dynamically and use object constructor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, firebase

I'm pulling data with Ajax that changes every day. I want to package the data into  objects that have unique names. Currently I created a constructor that looks like something like this:

```
function myObject(Id,thing1,thing2,thing3) 
{
    this.Id = Id;
    this.thing1 = thing1;
    this.thing2 = thing2;
    this.thing3 = thing3;
}
```

then I push that to an array in a loop like this

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
    array.push(new myObject(value1,value2,value3,value4));
}
```

This works fine for what I'm doing but I just get an array with [object,object,object,object] inside of it which I can access with array[0] , array[1], etc.

but now I want to store those objects in firebase and would need to reference them so how could I have them named uniquely?

normally you would do

```
var thingid1 = new myObject(value1,value2,value3,value4));
var thingid2 = new myObject(value1,value2,value3,value4));
```

but this is all being created on the fly and sometimes there is 1 object created and sometimes 10.

I'm new at this and I've looked everywhere so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No I know i do call it something else I was just using that as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Id (value1) is unique...

```
var myObjectContainer = {};
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i += 1)
{
    myObjectContainer[value1] = new MyObject(value1,value2,value3,value4);
}
```